# FILTER_VALIDATE_URL doesn't work

Tags: php, validation, url

I'm trying to write some php that will check if an url exist and is working. I ran into a problem, and here is my code:

```
        if(!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === false)
        {
            //Trouve l'host
            $hostname=parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);

            //Tente de trouver l'adresse IP de l'host
            if (gethostbyname($hostname) !== $hostname)
            {
                //Cherche les données de l'entête
                $headers=get_headers($url);

                //Tente de trouver une erreur 404
                if(!strpos($headers[0], '404'))
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
```

The first line should check if my url is at least valid and the rest of my code correctly check that the host exist and that the link doesn't give me an error 404, but it consider my address O.K. if I write something like:

(Absolutely ANYTHING)://www.google.com

WHY?

Comment: What is the URL that you're testing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is correct, although it is very hard to read. It's much easier to read the code below instead:

```
if(filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) !== false)
```

The problem is that `filter_var` seems to accept any protocol. According to [Validate filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) page:

> Beware a valid URL may not specify the HTTP protocol `http://` so further validation may be required to determine the URL uses an expected protocol, e.g. `ssh://` or `mailto:`.

For example, see [this PHP bug #64173](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64173).

Your best bet is to supplement `filter_var` with additional testing for acceptable protocols, or use regular expressions to validate your URL.